# Rolling sum for last 3 hour records of just one column in SAS

Tags: sql, sas, datastep

Everyone,
What I need is to calculate for every record (every row) for the last 3 hour sum of usage (Usage is one of the columns in dataset) grouped by User and `ID_option`. 
Every line(row) represent one record (one hour have about million records). For example I made a table with just a few records (including desired column `sum_usage_3 hour`):

```
User  ID_option          time             usage        sum_usage_3hr
1         a1        12OCT2017:11:20:32       3             10
1         a1        12OCT2017:10:23:24       7             14
1         b1        12OCT2017:09:34:55       12            12
2         b1        12OCT2017:08:55:06       4              6
1         a1        12OCT2017:07:59:53       7              7
2         b1        12OCT2017:06:59:12       2              2
```

I have tried with something like this code below and it returns me a sum of all time, not just the last 3 hour. I'm not surprised, but I have not so much idea how I'm going to do this in `SAS`.

```
proc sql:
CREATE table my_table
SELECT *, SUM(usage) AS sum_usage_3hr
FROM prev_table WHERE time BETWEEN TIME and intnx('second', time, -3*3600)
GROUP BY User, ID_option;
RUN;
```

Any help is welcomed, thanks. It's not necessary to do this in `proc sql`, data step is also acceptable if it's possible. I just assume that I need some kind of partition by.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try **Proc expand** (if you have ETL package) http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/63939/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_expand_sect034.htm

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use a correlated sub-query to get the sum?

```
data have ;
  input user id_option $ datetime :datetime. usage expected ;
  format datetime datetime20.;
cards;
1 a1 12OCT2017:11:20:32  3  10
1 a1 12OCT2017:10:23:24  7  14
1 b1 12OCT2017:09:34:55 12  12
2 b1 12OCT2017:08:55:06  4   6
1 a1 12OCT2017:07:59:53  7   7
2 b1 12OCT2017:06:59:12  2   2
;
proc print; run;

proc sql ;
create table want as
  select a.*
       , (select sum(b.usage) 
          from have b
          where a.user=b.user and a.id_option=b.id_option
            and b.datetime between intnx('hour',a.datetime,-3,'s') and a.datetime
         ) as usage_3hr 
  from have a
;
quit;
```

Results

```
                                                                         usage_
Obs    user    id_option                datetime    usage    expected      3hr

 1       1        a1          12OCT2017:11:20:32       3        10         10
 2       1        a1          12OCT2017:10:23:24       7        14         14
 3       1        b1          12OCT2017:09:34:55      12        12         12
 4       2        b1          12OCT2017:08:55:06       4         6          6
 5       1        a1          12OCT2017:07:59:53       7         7          7
 6       2        b1          12OCT2017:06:59:12       2         2          2
```

Comment: I'm testing this code now. It looks good, but work about one hour and still counting.

Comment: Is it need to be sorted by some column before aggregation (sum)? Maybe that causes the problem.

Comment: If your data is large you can probably get a more efficient result using SAS/ETS procedures like PROC EXPAND.  Or using a data step and taking advantage of your knowledge of the sort order of the data.

Answer (score 1):

The result is not surprising, as the condition for the WHERE clause is always true (time is necessarily greater or equal (or lesser or equal) to time).

I believe the simplest way would be to join the table on itself, and select the relevant rows this way:

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
        select  distinct a.*
                ,sum(b.USAGE) as sum_usage_3hr
            from have as a
            left join have as b
                on a.USER = b.USER
                    and a.ID_OPTION = b.ID_OPTION
                    and b.TIME between intnx('hour', a.TIME, -3) and a.TIME
        group by a.USER, a.ID_OPTION, a.TIME;
quit;
```

Comment: That needs a GROUP BY or SAS will sum() over the whole result set and re-merge the same value for sum_usage_3hr onto all observations.

Comment: That is a very good point. Added a DISTINCT to remove duplicate rows. Your answer is much more elegant though. :)